# Openlayers 4 - Load WMS image source require authentication

Tags: openlayers, wms, authentication, typescript

I try to load WMS image layer with openlayers 4.6 and angular 5, the code is:

```
const syr_layer = new ol_layer_Image({
  source: new ol_source_ImageWMS({
      url: 'serverurl', crossOrigin: 'anonymous', serverType: 'geoserver',
      params: { 'LAYERS': 'tst:syr'},
      projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });
});
```

But it throws an error:

> GET (myserverurl) 401 (An Authentication object was not found in the
>   SecurityContext)

How can I send authentication header with the GET request sent by openlayers?